# Handling Multiple OAuth code query parameters

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using 2 Oauth services in my website. They both send back a query parameter called `code`. And I use a custom function to grab that `code` field when my page loads. Do OAuth services have a way you can change that code field to be custom? I am using Google OAuth for one and I am unable to locate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [standard specifies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2) that the query parameter is named `code`, so there's no way to name them differently.

But the client can add a `state` parameter to the authorization request, which the authorization server has to return with the code. You can use that parameter to distinguish between the two authorization requests.